# pandas DataFrame concat / update ("upsert")?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an elegant way to append all the rows from one DataFrame to another DataFrame (both DataFrames having the same index and column structure), but in cases where the same index value appears in both DataFrames, use the row from the second data frame.

So, for example, if I start with:

```
df1:
                    A      B
    date
    '2015-10-01'  'A1'   'B1'
    '2015-10-02'  'A2'   'B2'
    '2015-10-03'  'A3'   'B3'

df2:
    date            A      B
    '2015-10-02'  'a1'   'b1'
    '2015-10-03'  'a2'   'b2'
    '2015-10-04'  'a3'   'b3'
```

I would like the result to be:

```
                    A      B
    date
    '2015-10-01'  'A1'   'B1'
    '2015-10-02'  'a1'   'b1'
    '2015-10-03'  'a2'   'b2'
    '2015-10-04'  'a3'   'b3'
```

This is analogous to what I think is called "upsert" in some SQL systems --- a combination of update and insert, in the sense that each row from `df2` is either (a) used to update an existing row in `df1` if the row key already exists in `df1`, or (b) inserted into `df1` at the end if the row key does not already exist.

I have come up with the following

```
pd.concat([df1, df2])     # concat the two DataFrames
    .reset_index()        # turn 'date' into a regular column
    .groupby('date')      # group rows by values in the 'date' column
    .tail(1)              # take the last row in each group
    .set_index('date')    # restore 'date' as the index
```

which seems to work, but this relies on the order of the rows in each groupby group always being the same as the original DataFrames, which I haven't checked on, and seems displeasingly convoluted.

Does anyone have any ideas for a more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

One solution is to conatenate `df1` with new rows in `df2` (i.e. where the index does not match).  Then update the values with those from `df2`.

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]])
df.update(df2)

>>> df
             A   B
2015-10-01  A1  B1
2015-10-02  a1  b1
2015-10-03  a2  b2
2015-10-04  a3  b3
```

**EDIT:**
Per the suggestion of @chrisb, this can further be simplified as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)], df2])
```

Thanks Chris!

Comment: Nice.  I am also wondering about efficiency.  This approach definitely seems more efficient than my groupby solution, but it looks like it would still involve passing over the data in both df1 and df2 multiple times (in terms of what pandas has to do internally, I mean).  If anyone has thoughts about an even more efficient approach, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: You could avoid the update by writing in the reverse order; `pd.concat([df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)], df2])`

Comment: @embeepea well YMMV. but this actually is quite efficient, involves one set op (on the index) and 1 take (the indexing), and a single copy (the concat). Eg. 1MM rows, takes 150ms on my machine.

Answer (score 12):

As of **pandas 1.0.3**, the desired functionality is directly given by [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```py
combined = df2.combine_first(df1)

print(combined)
#               A   B
# 2015-10-01    A1  B1
# 2015-10-02    a1  b1
# 2015-10-03    a2  b2
# 2015-10-04    a3  b3
```

To get this behaviour, the dataframe whose data has priority (the updating one, in this case `df2`) must be the one calling the function.

It basically: (1) harmonizes rows and columns, (2) gives priority to non-NaN data, and (3) if datapoints defined in both dataframes, gives priority to data in `df2`, which is essentially what you want.

**EDIT:** My understanding is that `combine_first` *does* fulfill the requested "update-if-present-insert-if-absent" behaviour. However, according to Vijchti in the comments (thanks), this does not strictly correspond to an SQL UPSERT manipulation, as the logic is applied value-by-value instead of the entire row. I removed any reference to UPSERT from my answer.

Comment: An UPSERT operation is a row-by-row insertion or replacement. A combine_first operation is value-by-value. These are not equivalent operations. If you use UPSERT, then a new row will completely replace an existing row. If you use combine_first, then non-null values of a new row will replace only null values of an existing row (and all existing non-null values will remain in place).

Comment: and what is UPSERT?  is it the same solution as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the correct answer, watch out for columns that do not exist in both dataframes:

```py
    df1 = pd.DataFrame([['test',1, True], ['test2',2, True]]).set_index(0)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame([['test2',4], ['test3',3]]).set_index(0)
```

If you just use the aforementioned solution as-is, you get:

```py
    >>>     1   2
    0       
    test    1   True
    test2   4   NaN
    test3   3   NaN
```

But if you are expecting the following output:

```py
    >>>     1   2
    0       
    test    1   True
    test2   4   True
    test3   3   NaN
```

Just change the statement to:

```py
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2[~df2.index.isin(df1.index)]])
    df1.update(df2)
```