# Merging dataframes in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I am new to pandas and I am facing the following problem:

I have 2 data frames:

df1 :

```
x  y
1  3 4
2  nan
3  6
4  nan
5  9 2
6  1 4 9
```

df2:

```
x  y
1  2 3 6 1 5
2  4 1 8 7 5
3  6 3 1 4 5
4  2 1 3 5 4  
5  9 2 3 8 7
6  1 4 5 3 7
```

The size of the two is same.

I want to merge the two dataframes such that all the resulting dataframe i get is the following:

result :

```
x  y
1  3 4 6 1 5
2  4 1 8 7 5
3  6 3 1 4 5
4  2 1 3 5 4
5  9 2 3 8 7
6  1 4 5 6 7
```

So in the result, priority is given to df2. If there is a value in df2, it is put first and the remaining values are put from df1 (they have the same position as in df1). There should be no repeated values in the result (i.e if a value is in position 1 in df1 and position 3 in df2, then that value should come only in position 1 in the result and not repeat)

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you want to continue to use the dataframe, I would re-shape the data to have the columns `x, y0, y1, y2, y3, y4` and then use pandas replace, which you can read about here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace data from one pandas dataframe to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419040/replace-data-from-one-pandas-dataframe-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

#### Setup

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(1, 7),
                        y=[[3, 4], None, [6], None, [9, 2], [1, 4, 9]]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(1, 7), y=[[2, 3, 6, 1, 5], [4, 1, 8, 7, 5],
                                          [6, 3, 1, 4, 5], [2, 1, 3, 5, 4],
                                          [9, 2, 3, 8, 7], [1, 4, 5, 3, 7]]))


print df1
print
print df2

   x          y
0  1     [3, 4]
1  2       None
2  3        [6]
3  4       None
4  5     [9, 2]
5  6  [1, 4, 9]

   x                y
0  1  [2, 3, 6, 1, 5]
1  2  [4, 1, 8, 7, 5]
2  3  [6, 3, 1, 4, 5]
3  4  [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
4  5  [9, 2, 3, 8, 7]
5  6  [1, 4, 5, 3, 7]
```

convert to something more usable:

```
df1_ = df1.set_index('x').y.apply(pd.Series)
df2_ = df2.set_index('x').y.apply(pd.Series)

print df1_
print
print df2_

     0    1    2
x               
1  3.0  4.0  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  6.0  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  9.0  2.0  NaN
6  1.0  4.0  9.0

   0  1  2  3  4
x               
1  2  3  6  1  5
2  4  1  8  7  5
3  6  3  1  4  5
4  2  1  3  5  4
5  9  2  3  8  7
6  1  4  5  3  7
```

Combine with priority given to `df1` (I think you meant `df1` as that what was consistent with my interpretation of your question and the expected output you provided) then reducing to eliminate duplicates:

```
print df1_.combine_first(df2_).apply(lambda x: x.unique(), axis=1)

   0  1  2  3  4
x               
1  3  4  6  1  5
2  4  1  8  7  5
3  6  3  1  4  5
4  2  1  3  5  4
5  9  2  3  8  7
6  1  4  9  3  7
```